# how we can identify response time between lr_start_transaction(); and lr_end_transaction();

Tags: scripting, response, loadrunner

lr_start_transaction();

req1;

req2;

req3;

lr_end_transaction();

It just a basic question.

how can we know the response time of each request separately without adding any function in between? is there any ways to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an HTTP application, you can:

a) turn on Automatic transactions.   The first parameter in each web_* function will become the transaction name.   But, this will become cumbersome because you will get all transactions in the script.

b) You can use nested transactions

```
lr_start_transaction("foo");

     lr_start_transaction("req1");
          req1;
     lr_end_transaction("req1",LR_AUTO);

     lr_start_sub_transaction("req2","foo");
          req2;
     lr_end_sub_transaction("req2",LR_AUTO);

     req3;

lr_end_transaction("foo",LR_AUTO);
```

Notice how loadRunner supports both nested transactions as well as sub transactions, depending upon your need.

c) Take the timing outside of LoadRunner altogether by enabling time-taken in the HTTP logs.   You then pull the request logs at the end of the test and use a log processing tool to collect the data you are interested in.   If you desire to, you can import the name value pair data for the timing records back into LoadRunner analysis for reporting.   These show up as datapoints for reporting.

And, this is why your management owes you training and a mentor.  This material is covered in training class for LoadRunner.  If management wants you to use a tool, then they owe you a path to success through training and mentorship.